# How to add user input from textbox into an array or arraylist

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I am creating a gift card application where the user inputs the recipients information into textbox.  The app allows the user to add another gift card(up to 5 times).  I am trying to find a way to add the textbox input into an array or arrayList that I can call later and display that info in their "shopping cart".  The app is in C# with a webform platform in Visual Studio 2012.  So far, for the arraList, I have:

```
private ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   arrayList.Add(txtFName.Text);

   if (arrayList.Count == 1)
   {
      lblFName.Text = arrayList[0].ToString();
   }

   if (arrayList.Count == 2)
   {
      lblFName.Text = arrayList[0].ToString();
      lblFName1.Text = arrayList[1].ToString();
   }
}
```

I believe I just need a way to increment the input into the array but I cannot figure out how to do it.  Any help or suggestions on another avenue to take would be deeply apreciated

Here is the code for the recipient info panel as well as the panel for the Cart.
//

### Recipient Information:

The name of the person that will receive the Visa Prepaid Card is required. The name will appear on the card.

*First Name: 
                
                
                    
                    
                
                
                
                
                    Middle Initial: 
                
                
                    
                
                
                
                
                    *Last Name:
                
                
                    
                    
                
                
                
                
                    Suffix: 
                
                
                    
                        
                        Jr.
                        Sr.
                        II
                        III
                        IV
                       
                    
                
                
                
                The combination of first name, middle initial, last name, and suffix cannot exceed 26 characters.

### Gift Card Information:

Must be a whole amount between $25.00 and $500.00, without a dollar sign or decimal.
            
            
            
                
                    *Enter Amount: 
                
                
                    
                    
                
                
                
                
                    Personalized Message: 
                
                
                    
                        
                        All the Best
                        Bon Voyage
                        Congratulations
                        Congratulations Grad
                        Good Luck
                        Happy Anniversary
                        Happy Birthday
                        Have Fun
                        Just Because
                        Just Married
                        Merry Christmas
                        Seasons Greetings
                        Thank You
                    
                
                
                
                **Or Choose**   
                
                
                
                
                    Custom Message:

- CANCEL
- BACK
- CONTINUE

//

```
    //<asp:Panel ID="pnlCart" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="false">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" GroupingText="Card Choice 1" ForeColor="DarkBlue" Font-Bold="True" BorderStyle="NotSet" BorderColor="#E0E0E0">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="pair">
                    <div class="labelLeftBold">
                        Amount:
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldRight">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCartAmount" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="labelLeftBold">
                        Card Design: 
                    </div>
                    <div class="imgCard">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgCardChoice1" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldRight">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCartDesign" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="labelLeftBold">
                        Name on Card: 
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldRight">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCartName" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="labelLeftBold">
                        Message on Card: 
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldRight">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCartMessage" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <div class="container1">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" GroupingText="Card Choice 2" ForeColor="DarkBlue" Font-Bold="True" BorderStyle="NotSet" BorderColor="#E0E0E0">
                <div class="pair">
                    <br />
                    <div class="labelLeftBold">
                        Amount: 
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldRight">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCartAmount1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="labelLeftBold">
                        Card Design: 
                    </div>
                    <div class="imgCard">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgCardChoice2" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldRight">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCartDesign1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="labelLeftBold">
                        Name on Card: 
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldRight">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCartName1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="labelLeftBold">
                        Message on Card: 
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldRight">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCartMessage1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
           // </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: create a count variable and use that to determine which index will the data go to in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all who helped.  I solved the problem using ViewState and a few other modifications.

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [Serializable]
    class Recipient
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Recipient recipients = new Recipient();

        List<string> recipient = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];


        if (recipient == null)
        {
            recipient = new List<string>();
        }
        recipients.name = txtFName.Text.Trim();
        recipient.Add(recipients.name);
        ViewState["recipientList"] = recipient;

        if (recipient.Count == 1)
        {
            lblFName.Text = recipient[0];
        }

        if (recipient.Count == 2)
        {
            lblFName1.Text = recipient[1];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only ever 5 values then you could do this.

```
string[] values = new string[5];

values[0] = lblFName.Text;
values[1] = lblFName2.Text; // etc
```

Then to set the textbox values use this

```
lblFName.Text = values[0];
lblFName2.Text = values[1];
```

It doesn't matter if values[i] is equal to null as string can be a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `List`?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Control[] aryCtrl = new Control[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, dropdownlist1, dropdownlist2, dropdownlist3 };
   List<string> list = new List<string>();

   foreach (Control ctrl in aryCtrl)
   {
      list.Add(textbox1.Text);
      list.Add(textbox2.Text);
      list.Add(textbox3.Text);
      list.Add(dropdownlist1.Text);
      list.Add(dropdownlist2.Text);
      list.Add(dropdownlist3.Text);
   }
}
```

I create a `Control[]` array:

```
Control[] aryCtrl = new Control[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3 };
```

I use this in my `foreach` loop.  Next, as I mentioned in my original answer, I created a `List` object to store the data from the textboxes/dropdowns.  Lastly, using a `foreach` loop, I spin through the `Control[]` array and add the `.text` value of each control.

Edited.  This should work for you, OP!

Comment: The user input will be the recipients name, card type(ie.. Visa, MasterCard) and the amount to put on the card.  I did try something similar to this with no luck.  How do I tie the List in with the textbox input?

Comment: Are all input fields textboxes?  Or are there dropdowns too?

Comment: Yes, they are both textbox and dropdowns

Comment: The problem I am seeing so far is that the for loop is populating the list with 5 values.  I am trying to make it increment only once per recipient added.  That way when the user gets to the shopping cart a new panel is visible with the new recipient added.  By the way, if pertinent, this is all done on one .aspx document with various hidden panels for different parts of the website.  It is only 1,024 lines long and this is my last hurdle to completing it.

Comment: How many controls are there, in total?  As in, which textbox does what, and how many of them?  How many dropdowns, and which fields do they relate to?  I try to make my answers as precise as possible.

Comment: textboxes = FName, LName, Minitial Dropdowns = card type, personal message(ie.. Happy Brthday etc.), Suffix  Those are the only controls that are added to the shopping cart.

Comment: I understand and believe that this could work however, Visual Studios is unhappy with list.Add(ctrl.Text), mainly the text part.  Would ctrl.ToString() work?

Comment: What is the exception or warning you are seeing?

Comment: The generic System.Web.UI.Control does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text'....

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think I understand what you are trying to do here.

Create a simple class to store the data.

```
 Class Recipient
 {
      string Name { get; set; }
      string CreditCardName { get; set; }
      string Amount { get; set; }
      string Message { get; set; }
 }
```

Obviously you can change the datatypes to whatever you want (i.e. Amount could be a double).

Now you have your control array (which you technically don't even need) and Recipient list declared outside of the `button1_Click` event.

```
Control[] aryCtrl = new Control[] { 
                                   txtName, 
                                   cbxCreditCardName, 
                                   txtAmount, 
                                   txtMessage };

var recipients = new List<Recipient>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (recipients.Count < 5)
    {
       var recipient = new Recipient();

       recipient.Name = txtName.Text;
       recipient.CreditCardName = cbxCreditCardName.SelectedValue;
       recipient.CreditCardNumber = txtCreditCardNumber.Text;
       recipient.Amount= txtAmount.Text;
       recipient.Message= txtMessage.Text;

       recipients.Add(recipient);
    }
    else {
         //Provide user with message telling them that they can only have up to 5 recipients.
    }
}
```

It would also be a good idea to have a way to remove recipients from the list.

Comment: Thank you so much, this does work.  The only problem is that when the button is clicked, a new list is made. I need all items to be saved into the list so when the user adds a new name for example, the first label displays the first person and when another name is entered and the button is clicked the first label is still displayed and the second label displays the second person and so on until up to 5 new names are added.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am thinking that putting the list in view state may be a good way to go